# Use stylelint to check if vendor prefixes exist

Tags: continuous-integration, stylelint

I am looking for a way to prevent a Webpack/SCSS/Postcss/CSS pipeline to create css files **without** vendor prefixes.

We use `autoprefixer` to apply vendor prefixes. In the past this build had been accidently disabled and the IE 11 build was broken.

I understand that `Stylelint` has [rules](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/value-no-vendor-prefix) that check if there is a vendor prefix and then throw an error etc. Is there a way I can achieve the opposite with stylelint. I am open to write/extend a rule or plugin for that feature.

Alternatively: Any other solution not requiring Stylelint would be acceptable for me - as long as it has been proven to work.